# Grub rescue appears, no Windows disk

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

Also posted to Microsoft Support Forums and Dell Support Forums:

I once tried dualbooting all my other Windows installations with Ubuntu. However, there was some compications when the Gnu grub terminall appeard, I managed to boot into windows, deleted the partiton Ubuntu was installed on, then restarted. The Grub rescue
appeared. I tried every solution i could find, but they didnt work and they ended up using the Windows installation disk which i do not have. Please help

Comment: `deleted the partiton Ubuntu was installed on` ... the boot partition is probably somewhere else ... you will need to research how to make the windows partition bootable

Comment: i couldn’t fond any info, btw i know almost nothing about linux or grub

Comment: it's not a question about grub or about linux ... it is `how to make windows partition bootable?`

Comment: i get results of things i already tried and failed

Comment: i believe that you can download the windows install disk from microsoft

Comment: Welcome @SuperAviationFan117 !
I see you need help, but keep in mind that you did not format your question like an actual question (but a request), which won't work well on this website. Try rewording it with exactly what do you want to have answered, so you can get more directed answers for what you need (which are also more relevant to other people). If you want to "fix" grub and keep the dualboot, state it clearly. Otherwise, if you want to restore the system to Windows only, you should get more help by moving your question to https://superuser.com/ .